# InDesign: shift baseline by percentage amount

Tags: adobe-indesign, page-layout, formatting, character-styles

I know I can enter horizontal and vertical scales as percentages, but the baseline can only be entered by points. Is there any way to go around this with a percentage value?

[image: Character Style Options, Advanced Character Formats menu]

Comment: Percentage of what? The line spacing? The letter's x-height or cap height?

Comment: Percentage of the font size (pts)

Comment: @Esoria - if that's the case, then you can just work it out with a calculator. For example, if the font size is 12pt, and you want a 10% baseline shift, it's simply 12*10% (i.e. 1.2pt).

Comment: For people who dont know. You dont have to use a calculator @BillyKerr all computers are calculators and adobe dialogs allow you to do limited calculation so you can actually type 12pt * 0.10 into a dialog and the software calculates it to you. it even understands units so if you want to mix millimetets and inches just go ahead. But i said limoted no parentheses or multiple calculations, so if you want to chain stuff tab oit of tge dialog in between calcs

Comment: @joojaa, Absolutely. I am apt to forget that feature exists!

Answer (score 1):

Probably not. Baseline shift works in your current unit of measurement, points, millimeters, etc. It does that because the Baseline grid itself is defined in 'pt' or 'mm', and not in percentages. However, you can do the math with a calculator and find out what percentage you need, also, if you type in '1 pt' in the box, then go back and type in 400%, see what happens. This may or may not be helpful as the purpose is not very clear.

- https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/formatting-characters.html